# Menu link in WordPress doesn't work on ByetHost

Tags: wordpress

I created a website in on my local host using WordPress and it worked fine. But when I uploaded it to ByetHost, the menu link doesn't work.

For example:

On my local host, I enter the URL `localhost:8080/900feet/about/` to go to the About page and it works.  However, after uploading to ByetHost and entering the URL `http://wkelvin1991.byethost17.com/php/wordpress/900feet/about`, I am redirected to the wrong page.

I have tried `http://wkelvin1991.byethost17.com/900feet/wp-content/themes/mythemes/page-about` and `/page-about.php` and it still doesn't work.

I believe the link is wrong, but I don't know how to fix it or access my About page once uploaded to ByetHost.

Comment: Have you tried to change the site url on wp-admin configuration? it seems to be a htaccess issue.

Comment: Here http://wkelvin1991.byethost17.com/php/wordpress/900feet/wp-admin you go to Configuration and put on both URL inputs the following address http://wkelvin1991.byethost17.com/php/wordpress/900feet, i assume that's showing your old local url http://localhost:8080/900feet/